# Android PhoneGap ajax (json call)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I have a Android app that contains a ajax json call to my remote server. I've tested the app with eclipse, a emulator (Ripple) and tested the ajax script in a browser on my local server. All tests work perfectly but when I upload my app to PhoneGap Build and test the apk file on my phone it returns a status 0 on the ajax call. What am I doing wrong? Can there be a difference between the emulator and the apk?

Ajax call:

```
var formData = $("#form-id").serialize();

$.ajax({
url: "https://mydomain.com/file.php",
data: formData, 
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data){
    if(data['login'] == 'correct' && data['token'] != 'undefined' ){ 

        window.localStorage["token"] = data['tokenMyMen'];      
        notifyAlert('Login correct', 'Login');

    }else{
        notifyAlert('Login incorrect', 'Login');
    }

},          
error: function(x,e){
    if(x.status==0){
        notifyAlert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.', 'Error');
    }else if(x.status==404){
        notifyAlert('Requested URL not found.', 'Error');
    }else if(x.status==500){
        notifyAlert('Internel Server Error.', 'Error');
    }else if(e=='parsererror'){
        notifyAlert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed. '+x.status, 'Error');
    }else if(e=='timeout'){
        notifyAlert('Request Time out.');
    }else {
        notifyAlert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText, 'Error');
    }
}});
```

config.xml has `<access origin="https://mydomain.com" />`

Remote server has:

```
if($this->user->login($username, $password)){   

    $token = $this->user->getProperty('token');
    $createArray = array();             
    $createArray['login'] = 'correct';
    $createArray['token'] = $token;     

    $record = $createArray;
    echo json_encode($record);

}else{
    $record = array('login' => 'incorrect');                
    echo json_encode($record);
}
```